# "Take a photo" — why "take"?

Tags: etymology, verbs, colloquialisms

I don't understand why it's "**take** a photo". Why *take*? Is there any rule for this?

Comment: So what do you say in German (translated to English, please)? In French it is *prendre* (take) or *faire* (make, do).

Comment: @Drew _machen_ (make, do).

Comment: Germans say *aufnehmen* for videos. Why would you *take up* or *accept* a video? At least English makes sense, see the answers below. (And of course the only honest answer, for any language, is: you have to use *some* verb, so for all you care you can use any verb at all as long as enough people agree that that's the verb to use. If we collectively settle for "cat a photo" and "dog a video", then that's what you get. No word really *means* anything in and of itself. It is but a collection of sounds, and has whatever meaning we assign to it.)

Comment: These collocations are pretty much arbitrary.  You may as well ask why we "have" dreams and the Japanese "see" them, or why we think "of" someone but the Spanish think "in" them.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I disagree that "No word really means anything in and of itself", at least not in the sense that it seems that you've applied it arbitrarily to all languages. In Hebrew at least all words have a root, and one can know the verb by the root. For instance, לצלם a picture, the root is צלם which is the word for "image" as in "Man was created in the image of God". The root is ancient but in fact many roots can be found to have phonetic meanings, and almost certainly even those whose phonetic meanings are today not known, had them at some point in the past.

Comment: @dotancohen roots don't matter one bit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Thank you, that is an interesting read and influences my opinion of the subject! However though I agree that "lady" today no longer means "provider of bread", I still take the conservative approach of "drag on the etymological definition as long as possible" as opposed to the liberal social-media we-don't-learn-just-repeat-what-we-hear approach of "a word means whatever _I_ want it to mean because I didn't understand it the first time I heard it".

Comment: In English you dream *about* someone, but in Portuguese you dream *with* him.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I cannot think of any way to translate *aufnehmen* as *accept* (maybe you meant *annehmen*?), but when you consider that *auf* can translate to various prepositions, not just *up*, but also *on*/*onto*, it gets clearer: The photo gets "taken onto" a storage medium, onto the film. Possibly, the same reasoning might be applied to English.

Comment: I don't have enough proof to write an answer but I believe you take a picture/note because you take it from something. It's not created anew. Explaining a little: You take notes from some context(lecture/book/etc), you take photographs from some scene.
In contrast, when you write/draw you are creating something new, so you don't take them from anywhere.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems to be an extension of taking notes.

From "The Language of Photography"
http://www.source.ie/issues/issues2140/issue22/is22artlanpho.html

> *To photograph* exists alongside *to take a photograph*, *to take a picture*, and so on. This is an extension of a broad meaning of *take* 'to obtain or set down', as in *taking* notes or statements, 'to set down or get in writing'; more directly, it is an extension of a use recorded from the 17th century onwards in structures such as *taking pictures*, *likenesses*, or *portraits* 'to obtain or get a picture'. The specific photographic use seems to have driven out uses in relation to pictorial art - nowadays, we paint, draw, or produce portraits, and make or do drawings - so that *taking a picture* can only refer to photography.

Comment: Interestingly, "Notiz nehmen" is the correct German expression for "to take notice". Hence, one might as well ask why "machen" (to make) is used in German in connection with photography.

Comment: @painfulenglish Maybe because "to take notes" is "Notizen machen"?

Comment: I always thought it was "take a photo" like physically taking a physical photo from a Polaroid. I know photos were much older, this just made sense to me.

Answer (score 23):

In addition to the point made by Ronan, I think *take* belongs to the group of verbs that are semantically empty and are often christened *delexical verbs*. We often like to represent actions as nouns, often for maintaining an easy rhythm in speech.

So we 'take a walk', 'have/take a bath', 'have a read', 'have a look', 'take a dip', 'give a shove', 'give a laugh', 'make a promise' and so on.

In other words, don't think too much of the meaning of the verbs there!

Comment: There's also clearly a lot of regional variation here, as *take a look* is equally common in the US as *have a look*, and I've never personally heard an AmE speaker use *have a read*.

Comment: [Google: "have a read of this"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have+a+read+of+this%22).

Comment: @tobyink Yeah, exactly.  Which of those are US sources?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: it does come up in the [Ngram for AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+read&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20read%3B%2Cc0) though.

Comment: One can also 'take a crap' (defecate) even though one is clearly leaving it and 'give a crap' means something altogether different...

Comment: Very celebral.  I am going to have to take five before I can take a look at another question.

Comment: @emory Take your time. You may even want to take a seat so you can take this all in. All right, I'm spent. I'm gonna take off!

Comment: @pyobum take care

Answer (score 4):

Photography is about capturing the state of some photons within a moment (well, a very brief period of time). Once captured, the information about that state can be taken with you and reproduced anywhere. "Taking a photo" amounts to collecting information from the environment and carrying it away, i.e. literally the act of taking.

Peter provides some good examples of how "take" can be used in other scenarios where such reasoning doesn't make sense (I certainly don't carry a tub around with me whenever I "take a bath") but I think in this case, a literal meaning can and should be inferred.

I think my answer might be similar to Ronan's, but not enough to be a comment on that answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually ***make*** photos as well, although ***to take*** a photo is more prevalent.

[image: Google NGram for make vs take]

There are people on the Photography sub-site of StackExchange that determine their use based on what sort of action they are performing, noting subtle differences between to make and to take. See [Does a photographer take pictures or make pictures?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/does-a-photographer-take-pictures-or-make-pictures).

Comment: Wouldn't making pictures have existing long before photography though?

Comment: Ah, that does seem to be a fatal flaw in my reasoning! Hahaha

Comment: Also *making a picture* could mean *make a motion picture*, as in producing a movie.  This could also corrupt the results.

Comment: Fine artists often refer to their work as "making" photographs, to de-emphasize the passive connotations of "taking" photographs.

Comment: I think of ***take*** a picture or photo as the act of "capturing" the image, and to ***make*** a picture or photo as the act converting the stored image (digital or on film) to a printed photo.

Comment: Then clearly the top rated answer on the photography stackexchange has a broader idea of 'to make' than you

Answer (score 3):

If we go back to painting we have words and expressions that offer the very same relationship between painter and subject. For example to 'capture a likeness'.

Then let's go back to earlier, to the word 'draw'. To draw means to pull. To draw a horse and cart. To take from one place to another. To withdraw money from one account to another.

This idea is the same in other languages. A portrait in Italian for example is 'ritratto', trarre (traere) means to pull/draw. The etymology of portrait would suggest it also means to take a likeness from where it is towards you now.

Interestingly how also photos were often initially viewed as 'stealing' part of you.

All in all, when we talk about reproducing what we see via pencil, paint or photo we are taking it from it is to where we are now.

Answer (score 1):

There are only two verbs one can use in regards of using a camera to produce an image - 'take' and 'make'.

'Make' has am implied meaning of investing some effort - as in 'make dinner'.
'Take' feels more effortless.

Some years ago, photos were actually 'made' because it involved film processing, while now we just 'take' them.

Comment: Even then, we usually didn't **make** the photos ourselves, we hired someone to do it for us.

Comment: You can also _snap_ , _shoot_, _capture_ or simply _get_ a photo.

Comment: And the final paragraphis wrong too. People still 'make' pictures. This whole answer is decidedly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A Chinese perspective:

In Chinese, one verb/noun can have totally different meanings. "take a photo" in Chinese is "拍照", "拍" means clap, "照" means "photo". In some province in China people say "捏一张" which also means "take a photo". "捏" means "pinch", "一张" means "one piece".

So, what I want to say is, sometimes an existing verb may be 'borrowed' to invent a new meaning. The existing meaning no longer suitable in new phrase.

Sometime the verb is not important, it just picked make a noun become a verb or action.

Comment: Something to clarify is that "拍照" is specific to Mandarin. In other branches of Chinese the word might be different, for example in Cantonese it is "影相" (lit. "shadow shape") not "拍照".